# How to get end CGPoint of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgpoint

Is there a way to find the `endpoint` of the screen? Let's say a screen of size (100x100) have the midpoint at (50,) and starting point (0,) and the endpoint as (100,). I can hard code to get the end point based on the device screen size, but that would be a too much work based on assumptions.

I am making a custom `UIView` animation based on `UIBezierPath`.

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

As you can see the animation is stopped after it reaches some point.And I want this point to be the end of the screen,so that `UIView` is covered whole `screen`.  To be more clear, I drag the `UIView` to point A, and it animates to point B (end point,so B>A)

I am not sure how to calculate B, so that when I drag `UIView` to A, it animates to the end of the screen (endpoint of the screen).

Here is the code to get better understanding:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.dragView];

 if (touchLocation.x<250) {

        if (!startBackSlide) {
             _circleDragView.touchdragPoint=touchLocation.y;
            _circleDragView.dragToPoint=CGPointMake(touchLocation.x+40, touchLocation.y);
            [_circleDragView setNeedsDisplay];
            _savedPoint=touchLocation;
        }else{

            //move the top and bot points backwards along with slide
            [self animateCOmpleteBezier:touchLocation];

            _circleDragView.touchdragPoint=touchLocation.y;
            _circleDragView.dragToPoint=CGPointMake(touchLocation.x+54, touchLocation.y);
            [_circleDragView setNeedsDisplay];
            _savedPoint=touchLocation;

            if (touchLocation.x<20) {
                startBackSlide=NO;
                snapped=YES;
            }
        }

    }

    if (touchLocation.x>=250) {

        if (snapped) {
            snapped=NO;
            //move the top and bottom points to the specified point(In this case the end point)
        }

    }

}

-(void)animateCOmpleteBezier:(CGPoint) value{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 delay:0  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        _circleDragView.topWidthPoint=value.x-10;
        _circleDragView.botWidthPoint=value.x-10;
        [_circleDragView setNeedsDisplay];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];


}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking, do you want to simply get the device screen size?

Comment: no, as u see in the gif, i drag the view to point 100, and lift my finger up, then I expect the animation to move the view past the point 100, and at the end, the animation should make the view cover the whole screen, i mean the view should be dragged to end of the screen.

Comment: You could try the parent view's frame property.  Or walk up to the UIWindow.  Or use [`UIScreen mainScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIScreen/mainScreen).

Comment: Okay, yes, that sounds exactly like you need to get device screen size!?

Comment: does frame property give the required cgpoint I need ? I need a cgpoint which is exactly of 0 distance from the right end of the screen.

Comment: can this do the job   endPoint.x=self.view.frame.size.width;?

Comment: Why do you have _circleDragView.topWidthPoint=value.x-10;         _circleDragView.botWidthPoint=value.x-10; ? Why not just _circleDragView.topWidthPoint=value.x;         _circleDragView.botWidthPoint=value.x;

Comment: Because, I have not drawn the bezier path accurately, that covers the screen when the control point is changed. Hence I adjusted it by adding some padding to it.

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint of screen is equal to it's width and height:

```
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds